# How to set min postfix in Ion.RangeSlider?

Tags: jquery, slider, rangeslider

Right now I have something like this:

```
$("#my-age-slider").ionRangeSlider({
     min: <?php echo $value_min; ?>,
     max: <?php echo $value_max; ?>,
     from: 18,
     step: 1,
     postfix: " years",
     min_postfix: " year"
});
```

But the min_postfix doesn't work.

I have tried minPostfix: " year" too, but it doesn't work.

I need to have a singular label for the first value (in this case it's 1 year, instead of 1 years)

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does your slider works? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: Ok, I've checked the settings on the homepage, and there are no settings like `min_postfix`

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option as `min_postfix`. Please look at the settings description more carefully: https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider#settings

Comment: I don't understand why this is not a feature? In a date slider it makes perfectl sense to have a min_postfix, where you can show that there are dates older than the lowest one.

Comment: This feature is in plans.

Comment: also how about if you would like to use slider for instance for saturation and want to show icons instead of 0-100 values on sides?? I think there should be an optional parameter for min_label, max_label as well as min_postfix

Comment: or another use case, a slider to use 0 value for "ALL" , rest for numeric values, and last one for X+ ( X and more ) i.e available seats in a vehicle.

Comment: How can i use this slider for price slider with formatted values (min 1 L - max 1 Cr) and it should show runtime value changes with formatted type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
$('.irs-min').append('text');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Andrew's answer, I could fix my issue as per the below

```
$('.js-grid-text-0').append(' %');
$('.js-grid-text-1').append(' %');
```

...etc

[Ion Range Slider, with "postfix"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7esb.jpg)